# Simple short Encrypt string to fixed length n matter what the input string length is

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption

I would like to encrypt a string and it has to be decrypted back. The input string could be of varying length but the encrypted string must be a max of 15 characters and alphanumeric. This is for an intranet application, so security is not of a big concern. I should be able to decrypt it  back to match in another page. I am using vs2012, c#, asp.net. Please advice. I tried rijndael, but it gives a long string. The encrypted string must be user friendly since the user will need to remember and enter it.

Thanks,
DotNet

Comment: It's not possible to set a limit on encryption output length. Most encryptions actually increase the length of the data on output.

Answer (score 11):

> The input string could be of varying length but the encrypted string must be a max of 15 characters and alphanumeric.

This is clearly impossible. If you solved this, you would solve all possible storage concerns - after all, you'd be able to store *the whole internet* (viewed as one long string) in 15 alphanumeric characters (after decryption).

You haven't told us what the input string might consist of, either - assuming that by "alphanumeric" you mean A-Z, a-z, 0-9 that's only 62 possible characters. So there are 62<sup>15</sup> possible encrypted strings. If your input is in UTF-16 code units, then just *6* code units has more possibilities (65536<sup>6</sup> is greater than 62<sup>15</sup>).

Basically, you're onto a losing proposition here - you should rethink your design.

Perhaps you should store the original value in a server, return some token, and then be able to fetch the value when you want? That isn't encryption, but it *may* satisfy your real requirements.

Further reading: [the pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not looking for encryption but Hash algorithm. Hash algorithm generates Hash of specific length (not encrypted text).

Comment: He mentioned decrypting it back - that's not possible with a hash.

Comment: I know, might be he is confused with terminology.

Answer (score 0):

John skeet is almost right.

If you convert to an encryption of base 10 then convert back adding characters:

!@#$%^&*()_+-=;:'"<>,.?/\ to the 0-9, A-Z, a-z

then you will sometimes reduce the size and all the times it won't be recognizable.

basically convert to base 10 from a large base then convert that to a larger base

Comment: It's unclear which aspect of my answer you think is incorrect - or how your suggestion will satisfy the requirement of reversibly encrypting an arbitrary-length string into 15 characters.

Comment: lol I think I did a dyslexia *face-palm*. I thought it was the other way around

Comment: Thanks! My requirement is authenticate users on the fly and no storing of user information anywhere. Ex : a new user needs access to my website, they will come and request the admin to generate the password and they will give the username. The admin generates a password based on the username. Each time the user log in they use the username and admin given password. The way the application authenticates is generate the password based on the username using the same algorithm that the admin used to generate the password when giving to the user and compare it with the password entered by the user.

Comment: @user3557236 1) Edit your question to include the additional information 2) That description and your "it has to be decrypted back" requirement don't fit together. Why do you need to decrypt?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions! I had to generate the password using the same technique that my peer had used which is `SHA`.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username)));
```

Comment: and what can be the inverse of this?

Answer (score -1):

As Jon Skeet brings up, what you probably need is a *token*.  You'll need to store you data on the server (database?).  Use a token value as a key to retrieve the data.

If you don't need any security at all, you can use an Identity field (autoincrementing).  If you want to make it harder to guess, you'll need something like this:

```
    public static string GetRandomToken()
    {
        // create a guid and convert to a byte array
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();

        // xor the first 8 bytes with the last
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] ^ bytes[i + 8]);
        }

        // resize the array down to eight bytes
        Array.Resize<byte>(ref bytes, 8);

        // return the hexidecimal representation, with the last character lopped off
        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty).Substring(0, 15);

    }
```

This only handles generating a token with length of 15.  You still have to handle the database access yourself.

Comment: Don't use GUIDs for randomness, use them for uniqueness. They are designed to be unique, not random. They may look pretty random, but they are not as random as they look.